# Initial Context look up returning null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0, enterprise

I'm trying to find multiple EJBs by passing the mappedName of each one through a `while` calling a function named "getEJBBean", which uses the `.lookup` method, but it just returns null and I can't work out why?

Called with:

```
customeraccountclient = new CustomerAccountClient(getEJBBean("java:comp/env/ejb/customeraccountsfacade"));
```

Function:

```
public final Object getEJBBean(String beanName) {
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        return ctx.lookup(beanName);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("ERRORL While locating Server Bean: " + ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know it gets to here because it throws the error println, the best I can work out is the ctx.lookup is failing?

I don't know how to fix this and can't find anythign that makes it any clearer.

Comment: Where is this code being executed?

Comment: `new InitialContext()` only works when it is executed by code deployed to a Java EE application server.

Comment: It is being executed in a client application of my program, I'm trying to use it to access my SQL tables in another "project" that is also running

Comment: Lookup failed for 'customeraccountsfacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl}

Comment: You need to learn about remote EJBs and consult your server documentation to find out how to look them up from a remote client.

Comment: What's the application server you're using?

Comment: what's your server? if you see the console for your server you  can find all ejb started and jndi

Comment: see this if help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33251138/unable-to-get-remote-ejb-from-client-application-in-the-context-of-jboss/33438802#33438802